# text to speech - microsoft TTS SDK supports the Arabic language?

Tags: text-to-speech

i would like to know if the microsoft TTS SDK supports the Arabic language. If it does how? If it does not, is there any way to convert arabic text to speech?
please, i want my program to read arabic text using VB 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's TTS SDK (SAPI) is language-agnostic - it relies on TTS engines to actually transform the text to speech.

That being said, as far as I know, there are no free Arabic TTS engines available.

Acapela has an [Arabic male and female voice](http://www.acapela-group.com/acapela-tts-for-windows-8-speech-solutions.html) available for purchase, but I have no idea how much it costs.